# Opentype font not being used in Silverlight Windows Phone 7 app on deploy

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts, opentype

Is there a way to use an OpenType font on Windows Phone 7 Silverlight application? I want to use Lobster which is only available AFAIK in OpenType format. It renders in Blend but not when I deploy to the emulator.

I have included the .otf file in my project and set the Properties to 'Content' and 'Copy If Newer'.

[This website](http://www.markermetro.com/2011/06/technical/windows-phone-7-custom-fonts/) found a solution for .ttf fonts, but the technique specified does not work for OpenType. Is OpenType not supported by Windows Phone? I find this hard to believe given that MS part invented the format!

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone requires your fonts to be TrueType (.ttf). OpenType (.otf) is not supported.

Comment: I don't think it is as simple as "if the extension is `.ttf` it is ok" since Lobster downloaded from Google Web Fonts has a `.ttf` extension but does not work - I get impression that Lobster uses some of the advanced font features (multiple versions of the same letter for instance) these aren't supported on Windows Phone 7. Unfortunately I can't find clear documentation that specifies what is an isn't supported ...

Answer (score 1):

There may be some confusion on the term "OpenType". OpenType is a broad description of the format which actually includes 2 "flavors" for describing the font's outlines: TrueType and CFF (A form of Adobe PostScript).

A font with a .otf extension is most definitely an OpenType font, and usually means that it includes CFF outlines.

But a TrueType font is, in most cases, generally considered an OpenType font as well, since the OpenType format is actually a superset of both TrueType and CFF flavors.

Regarding Lobster in particular: as a test, I added that font to my Google Webfonts collection, and clicked "Download Collection". The resulting file was a .ttf, and as such, *should* be usable in Windows Phone as [Den Delimarsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14901138/1042788)'s answer points out. How are you getting a .otf version of this file? And is it truly a CFF file, or just a TrueType file with a .otf extension?

Also note that you may be able to obtain the TrueType/.TTF directly from the [Google Font Directory](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/) though doing so through a browser currently seems to be a bit wonky.

Comment: You are right, I can download Lobster as a `.ttf` file from Google Web Fonts. I was using Lobster 1.4 which I downloaded directly from the foundry website which is `.otf`. However even using the `.ttf` file still does not work on the emulator/device ...

Answer (score 1):

you need to add it to the project, set build action to content and enter a uri that links to it in the FontFamily property with the hash tag:

[image: Add it to the project]

[image: Set to Build Action 'CONTENT']

[image: Add Uri to property]

Example of FontFamily:

FontFamily="**fonts/Lobster.ttf#Lobster**"